# Can I style different GeoJSON layers using the same style function?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

I am new to Leaflet and JavaScript. I would like to know whether or not I can code my Leaflet map in a more concise way.

My map includes three GeoJSON layers in three different colors. I have set the colors by calling separate style functions for each layer. The function "style" returns blue, the function "style2" returns purple, and the function "style3" returns pink. I tell Layer 1 to use "style" and Layer 2 to use "style2", etc.

The map is here: http://talia.droppages.com/ask/three_layers.html

Can I do the same thing but with ONE style function? Essentially, could the style function detect the layer and do:

```
if the layer is layer 1, style like this______
if the layer is layer 2, style like this______
if the layer is layer 3, style like this______
```

If it can, how would I write that in code?

I frequently want to use ONE function for several layers, such as setting popup content, but I don't know how to make the function behave differently depending on which layer is clicked. I only know how to write similar but separate functions and call them separately.

```
<div id="map" style="width:800px; height: 600px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://talia.droppages.com/slccommcounc.js"></script>
<script src="http://talia.droppages.com/tract158slc.js"></script>
<script src="http://talia.droppages.com/slccouncil.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.8, -111.928], 11); 


    L.tileLayer('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 7
  }
  ).addTo(map); 

function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'cornflowerblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}
function style2(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'blueviolet',
        fillColor: 'plum',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}
function style3(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'fuchsia',
        fillColor: 'pink',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}

var layer1 = new L.geoJson(slccommcounc, {
    style: style,
}).addTo(map);

var layer2 = new L.geoJson(tract158slc, {
    style: style2,
})

var layer3 = new L.geoJson(slccouncil, {
    style: style3,
})

L.control.layers(null,{'Layer 1 Title':layer1,'Layer 3 Title':layer3,'Layer 2 Title':layer2},{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Comment: Best to specify _why_ you want to use one function for this: you're specifying three different styles. Even the most succinct function will be just choosing between the three - it will be more complex and less straightforward than using three functions.

Comment: @tmcw I see what you mean - one function would still break into parts. The reason I ask about one function is for concision in later scenarios with many more layers added to a map. Ex: Perhaps I have 10 layers which I want to have the exact same style properties except for the "color" property. It seems less redundant to have a color assignment made for each layer at the point of the color property rather than repeat the function and all of the settings 10 times. I'm very interested to know if that's possible and how it would be coded with Leaflet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a strategy that allows one style function instead of three. I just needed to learn how to pass a parameter into the style function. In this case the only changes were to color and fillColor, so those parameters are set when the layer is made. The result map looks exactly the same as the original map. Here is the more concise code:

```
<div id="map" style="width:800px; height: 600px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="slccommcounc.js"></script>
<script src="tract158slc.js"></script>
<script src="slccouncil.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.8, -111.928], 11); 

L.tileLayer('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 7
  }
  ).addTo(map); 

function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: color,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}

var layer1 = new L.geoJson(slccommcounc, {
    style: style(color= 'blue', fillColor = 'cornflowerblue'),
}).addTo(map);

var layer2 = new L.geoJson(tract158slc, {
    style: style(color= 'blueviolet', fillColor = 'plum'),
})

var layer3 = new L.geoJson(slccouncil, {
    style: style(color= 'fuchsia', fillColor = 'pink'),
})

L.control.layers(null,{'Layer 1 Title':layer1,'Layer 3 Title':layer3,'Layer 2 Title':layer2},{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

In my case, I did not color layers based on any particular property. Note that if you want to style a layer based on a property already set in the GeoJson, Leaflet gives an example of that here:
http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.Not the cleanest but it works.

```
    function style(opt) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 's1':
                color = 'red';
                fillColor = 'cornflowerblue';
                break;
            case 's2':
                color = 'blueviolet';
                fillColor = 'plum';
                break;
            case 's3':
                color = 'fuchsia'
                fillColor = 'pink'
                break;
        }


    return {
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: color,
            fillColor: fillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        };
}

var layer1 = new L.geoJson(slccommcounc, {
    style: style('s1'),
}).addTo(map);

var layer2 = new L.geoJson(tract158slc, {
    style: style('s2'),
})

var layer3 = new L.geoJson(slccouncil, {
    style: style('s3'),
})
```