# Leaflet - once layer use more times?

Tags: leaflet, layer

I have Leaflet map with one date layer joined with:

```
<script src="data/Hranicesttu0.js"></script>

Function: 
        function pop_Hranicesttu0(feature, layer) {
        ...
        map.addLayer(layer_Hranicesttu0);

Legend is defined: 
        L.control.layers(baseMaps,{'<img src="legend/Hranicesttu0.png" /> Hranice státu': layer_Hranicesttu0,}
```

I need this Hranicesttu0.js reuse as another layer(s) (in legend too) without new file something.js. Is it possible?

Example: http://l.kelv.cz/

Comment: It is quite hard to understand your question. Could you reformulate with more details ?

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191845/can-i-style-different-geojson-layers-using-the-same-style-function (Is it possible delete own answer?)